# Is there any downside to changing Twitter Bootstrap from 940px fixed to 960px fixed?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking to use Twitter Bootstrap but the problem is that I need the content area to be 960px wide instead of only 940px that the Twitter Bootstrap default uses.

I do NOT want to use the responsive grid, but the fixed one, as 99% of users will access it through the computer or iPad, not mobile phones.

If I change the pixel widths of the rows and containers to end up with a 960px design, will it mess up anything big time?

I personally believe a 960px width is better than the 940px width and even on a resolution of 1024px/768px it still shows fine without horizontal scrollbars.

Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Responsive design does not only provide a better experience for users of small devices. It can also provides a better experience for users with a screenwidth above 1024 pixels ([which are most of pc users](http://gs.statcounter.com/#resolution-ww-weekly-201201-201230)).

The grid system used by Twitter is **exactly the same** (12 columns, 60px column width, 20px gutter) as used by the 960 grid system save for the 10px spacing on each side.

Comment: I always thought that the 960 grid was actually 960px wide, but as you say, the content does appear to be 940, just like in Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that twitter bootstrap has a margin-left:-20px on each row. 
That makes the 960px grid

```
.row {
  margin-left: -20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I if you don't want to create responsive site, and also with 960 grid sistem, you can use Bootstrap, but with changes. Big changes. Almost all framework. You could do that, or simply use other framework like [960.gs](http://960.gs/).